# Random CLA byte for JAVACARD

Tags: javacard

I am new to JAVA CARD and start doing a simple project. The aim of project is to get response from JAVA CARD after sending out command from the terminal. The difficulty is that the JAVA CARD should have the ability to response no matter what the request command is. However, from my understanding, the JAVA CARD command should follow the rules defined in ISO7816 - Part 4. May I know if it is possible to send a "0x1D" CLA command, JAVA CARD returns response after processing it?

I tried this in my simple code, but it returns "68 81" code indicating that "card does not support the operation on the specified logical channel"..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the class byte in JavaCard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929164/what-exactly-is-the-class-byte-in-javacard)

Comment: Hi Paul, seems like I should follow the rule defined by ISO78616-Part4 and card is not be able to response when random command sent. Thanks

Comment: yes everything can be random but the class byte, because it is interpreted by the card os

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks again for your clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot just randomize the class byte.

The ISO/IEC 7816-4 specifies a specific structure for the APDU header, which Java Card *mostly* complies to. Now the P1 and P2 are mostly random, but the CLA and INS parts of an APDU must be comply to a minimal set of rules.

Bits in the CLA for the logical channel are off limits. The implementation of logical channels is performed by the platform, not the applet (although the applet certainly should be programmed to support it). Card implemenations may not support logical channels or may only support a few logical channels.

The chaining and secure messaging bits are available because the implementation of chaining and secure messaging should take place by the applet.

Furthermore the combination INS=A4 and P1=04, INS=70 and - more importantly in this context - CLA=FF are problematic; the first one is used to select applets, the second to manage logical channels and the third is often used to indicate that the *reader* should handle the APDU rather than the card. You could see CLA=FF as an *escape*.

Comment: Hi Maarten, Thanks for your detailed explanation.